# Div container within main wrapper won't center

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I basically have a `#wrapper` , `#contentWrapper` , `#actualContent`

I have my `#wrapper` centering the viewport, with width `940px`; however I cant get my #actualContent to center within the main wrapper.

Any suggestions?

**[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecENa/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on your content div and `text-align:center` in your parent div. Also remove the `width:100%` from the content.

[**Here's the jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecENa/1/)

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 84px 0 0 0;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    padding: 27px 0 27px 0;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Comment: Zenith > Awesome - that did the trick! Weird that ive never used inline-block before - wonder how that have passed my knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I hope [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecENa/5/) is what you need.
You gave unnecessary `width` and `margin`